# Error: [ng:areq] reverse,split,join in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Pls find the error i am facing this error and find my code below

```
$scope.reverseStr=function()
            {
                return $scope.revStr.split('').reverse().join('');
            }
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/ng/areq?p0=reverseControl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: There is not enough code there to help you. Share your controller declaration too,

Comment: <html ng-app="">
<head>
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   function reverseControl($scope)
   {
   $scope.reverseStr=function()
   {
    return $scope.revStr.split('').reverse().join('');
   }
   }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="reverseControl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="revStr">
 the reverse String is {{reverseStr()}}!!!
   
</body>
</html>

Comment: Add it to the question not as comment